# Run Javascript on the h:outputtext value

Tags: javascript, jsf

I can't seem to get the code below working to run the javascript before displaying the value #{row.currentstring}.
Below is the JSF code responsible for showing the value

```
    <rich:column styleClass="#{row.displayClass}" >
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.currentvocab}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText id="vocab_value" value="get_vocab('#{row.currentString}')" styleClass="#{row.displayClass}" />
    </rich:column>
```

Here get_vocab is the javascript I am running which is shown below:

```
        function get_vocab(inp)
{
var b = "car";
var c = "propose";
var d = "check";
var x;
var y;
if (inp.indexOf(b) > -1) {
    x = inp.indexOf(b);
    y = inp.substring(0,x+3);
}
else if (inp.indexOf(c) > -1) {
    x = inp.indexOf(c);
    y = inp.substring(0,x+7);
}
else if (inp.indexOf(d) > -1) {
    x = inp.indexOf(d);
    y = inp.substring(0,x+5);
}
else {
    y = "value not found"
}
return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run `javascript` by putting it as the `value` attribute. If your `javascript` is included below the `h:textOutput` you can get the value and change it client side with javascript.

#### Change:

```
function get_vocab(inp)
{
  // ... rest of your logic ...
}
```

#### To:

```
function get_vocab()
{
  var span = document.getElementById("vocab_value");
  var inp = span.innerText;
  // ... rest of your logic without return ...
  span.innerText = y;
 }
```

#### Your jsf code

```
 <h:outputText id="vocab_value" value="#{row.currentString}" styleClass="#{row.displayClass}" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try the change and see :). will upvote and check mark after if it works.